# youtube api does not fire ENDED event when video ends (using iframe)

Tags: jquery, html, youtube-api

I'm trying to catch an event so that when a youtube player ends, I can then redirect to another web page.  but it does not work.  Can anyone spot anything wrong?  The javascript does seem to compile OK.

Here's the code of the entire page (I actually pasted it from the view-source page of the browser below.
    Its fairly simple, the event is listed in the onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() function and I assume it should fire when the code ends.  I've put in 'alert' to see if it does.  It looks like it does not:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        })


          // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
     //    after the API code downloads.
     function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
         player = new YT.Player('iframeid', {
             events: {   
                 'onReady': onPlayerReady,          
                 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
             }
         });
     }

     function onPlayerReady(event) {

     }
     function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

         if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
             alert("video is over");
             location.href= 'k_Origins.aspx';
         }
         else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {

         }
         else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {

         }
         else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {

         }
         else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED) {

         }
         else {

         }

     }

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="dostuff.aspx" id="form1">

<div id="ContainPlayer">

    <iframe id="iframeid" width="420" height="315"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8X0ZkN_EtTE?hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=1&autohide=0&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&playerapiid=ourvideoid&rel=0" 
    frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    </div>

    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in what you've pasted above; you left out an opening  tag before the 
line:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

so the javascript would never be interpreted by the browser. When I took your code and added that in, it ran just as you are wanting it to.

Comment: The typo was not the problem.  The problem was that my url had the origin attribute.  In other words, www.youtube.com/...origin=mysite.com.  This apparently interferes with the youtube api.  I should have put it in my sample, but I didn't want to give away my website.  It just shows you, you have to put in everything, whether you think its relevant or not.